# Edge.remove return's error

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-like

I send you this message because I've a little problem with the subscribe's edge.remove function in my contest application.

In my application, i would like to listen the like and dislike on the button for save it in the database to etablish the contest ranking. But i've a problem with the dislike function and it's distord my ranking.When i like the image, it's work, but when i dislike the previous like button, it's return a link who is called "error" (in red) witch linked to the following error :

"There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors.".

In firebug, Facebook return the following code by the url POST http://www.facebook.com/ajax/connect/external_node_connect.php?__a=1 call :

> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected" :false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info": {"brief":"An error occurred.","full":"There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors.", "errorUri":"/connect/connect_to_node_error.php?title=An+error+occurred.&body=There+was+an+error+liking+the+page.+If+you+are+the+page+owner\u00252C+please+try+running+your+page+through+the+linter+on+the+Facebook+devsite+\u002528https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fdevelopers.facebook.com\u00252Ftools\u00252Flint\u00252F\u002529+and+fixing+any+errors.&hash=AQBOwKwXHdofUaSJ"}}}

My code is :

```js
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
            appId  : '<?= APP_ID; ?>',
            status : true, 
            cookie : true, 
            xfbml  : true  
           }); 

           FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

           FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                function(href, widget) {
                    alert(href);
                    //$('a').bind('click',false);
                    //liketoggle(href);
                }
            );

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
                function(href, widget) {
                    alert('href');
                    //$('a').bind('click',false);
                    //liketoggle(href);
                }
            );

        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<?= APP_ID; ?>";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Note: Today it's working ! This is certainly a Facebook' bug of yesterday, thank's for your help !!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you passing too many parameters to that function? There should be only one.

Below one works for me:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        alert('You unliked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

And here is the documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe

Comment: I've tried to set one parameter as you tel me but is not work too =( Thank you again for your help it's nice!

Comment: Do what Andrew sais. Go to that page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ and paste the URL you want to like, it will tell you what's wrong with that URL.

Comment: I've already test the facebook developper debugger but nothing is wrong ans the like action is on but the dislike action dont work =(